# Overloading operator<< to work for string

Tags: c++, string, file-io, vector, operator-overloading

In the following code:

```
 using namespace std;

 //ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const string & str)
 //{    
 //  out << str.c_str();    
 //  return out; 
 //}

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {

     ofstream file("file.out");  

     vector<string> test(2); 

     test[0] = "str1"; 
     test[1] = "str2";
     ostream_iterator<string> sIt(file);

     copy(test.begin(), test.end(), sIt);

     file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

what is the proper way to overload `operator <<` to make
`copy(test.begin(), test.end(), sIt);` work.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm just stupid... forgot to include "string" header

Thank you!

Comment: To format code, use the 1010 button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to overload `operator<<` to work with strings, it already knows how to handle them.

```
std::copy( test.begin(), test.end(), 
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( file, "\n" ) );
```

will produce:

```
str1
str2
```

Is there anything different/special that you want to be done there?

Comment: I'm stupid!!! The reason why the above didn't work is actually funny:) (hint: missing include) p.s. sorry for the stupid question:)

Answer (score 2):

As David already pointed out, there is already a `operator<<` for strings, so you don't have to provide one. Should you really want to define your own overload anyway, then there's a slight problem, because actually you are not allowed to do that. `operator<<` is defined in the `std` namespace, so if you want to have a usable overload for `std::string` (the version in most implementations is a template function, so there *is* a potential overload), you'll have to do this in the `std` namespace too (this because of the ways ambiguities and overloads are resolved in C++, there are some caveats here) . For example:

```
namespace std {
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,const string & str)
  {     
    out << "A STRINGY:" << str.c_str();     
    return out; 
  }
}
```

However, adding stuff into the `std` namespace is not allowed for ordinary users, because it might have implementation specific effects that are unforeseeable and could break all kinds of stuff inside the standard library. Also, there is no guarantee, that your implementation of the standard library has a overloadable operator<<. This means, it could work or it could not.

Answer (score 1):

Lemme just add the link from cplusplus.com for future reference

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/